# What is the source of the following hadith which says good relations are better than fasting and prayer?

Tags: source-identification

In the internet the following hadith is quite [widespread](https://www.google.com/search?q=Do%20you%20know%20what%20is%20better%20than%20charity%20and%20fasting%20and%20prayer)

> Do you know what is better than charity and fasting and prayer? It is
>   keeping peace and good relations between people, as quarrels and bad
>   feelings destroy mankind." (Muslims & Bukhari)

But there is no hadith number mentioned *anywhere*. Is this authentic? If it is in Sahih bukhari then which hadith number is this?

Comment: they teach it in schools too! i've searched for it too never found a hadith number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one was tough to find a reference to, but it looks like this is the hadith being referred to:

> عَنْ أَبِي الدَّرْدَاءِ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ أَلاَ أُخْبِرُكُمْ بِأَفْضَلَ مِنْ دَرَجَةِ الصِّيَامِ وَالصَّلاَةِ وَالصَّدَقَةِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالُوا بَلَى ‏.‏ قَالَ ‏"‏ إِصْلاَحُ ذَاتِ الْبَيْنِ وَفَسَادُ ذَاتِ الْبَيْنِ الْحَالِقَةُ ‏"‏
>
> The Prophet (saws) said: “Do you want me to tell you of what is better than the rank of fasting, prayer and charity?” The Companions said, “Yes, O Messenger of Allaah. He said, “Making peace between people among whom there is discord, for the evil of discord is the shaver.”

This is in [Sunan Abi Dawud 4919](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43#147). There is another version in [Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2509](http://hadith.al-islam.com/Page.aspx?pageid=192&BookID=26&PID=2433) which adds that the Prophet (saws) said

> “It is the shaver, and I do not say that it shaves hair, but that it shaves (i.e., destroys) the *deen* (i.e. religious commitment).”

The version in Jami` Tirmidhi was authenticated as *sahih* by Shaykh al-Albani.

According to the translation on [islamqa](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/65500) this refers to *voluntary* acts of fasting, prayer, and charity. Which makes sense because the obligatory versions are nothing less than the pillars of Islam.

Comment: +1 indeed I tried quite hard to find it but couldn't because it is incorrectly attributed to Sahih Bukhari and Muslim.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is one too:
Abu'd-Darda' reported that the Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, said, "Shall I tell you a degree better than prayer, fasting and sadaqa?" "Yes," they replied. He went to say, Improving a state of friendship. Causing discord in a state of friendship is what shaves things away."

حَدَّثَنَا صَدَقَةُ، قَالَ‏:‏ حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو مُعَاوِيَةَ، عَنِ الأَعْمَشِ، عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ مُرَّةَ، عَنْ سَالِمِ بْنِ أَبِي الْجَعْدِ، عَنْ أُمِّ الدَّرْدَاءِ، عَنْ أَبِي الدَّرْدَاءِ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ‏:‏ أَلاَ أُنَبِّئُكُمْ بِدَرَجَةٍ أَفْضَلَ مِنَ الصَّلاَةِ وَالصِّيَامِ وَالصَّدَقَةِ‏؟‏ قَالُوا‏:‏ بَلَى، قَالَ‏:‏ صَلاَحُ ذَاتِ الْبَيْنِ، وَفَسَادُ ذَاتِ الْبَيْنِ هِيَ الْحَالِقَةُ‏.‏
Grade   : Sahih (Al-Albani)   صـحـيـح   (الألباني)  حكم     :
Reference    : Al-Adab Al-Mufrad 391
In-book reference    : Book 21, Hadith 7
English translation  : Book 21, Hadith 391